# Service class called by CRUD controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

## Context

I've defined a service class **validatePanel** which is called before a CRUD panel is actually rendered. The purpose of this class is to ensure that a sequence of distinct CRUDs are completed one after the other. A simple counter in the DB **NbSuivis** tracks the progression from panel to panel. The class simply redirects to the appropriate panel within the sequence.

Here is the class definition:

```
public static function validatePanel(int $NbPanel, int $NbSuivis, int $id): void

// $NbPanel = Panel number to be validated
// $NbSuivis = Last panel number which has been saved
// $id = id of model

    {

        switch ($NbPanel) {

            case 2: {

                    switch ($NbSuivis) {
                        case -1:
                            \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                            redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                            break;

                        case 0:
                            \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                            redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            case 3:
                switch ($NbSuivis) {
                    case -1:
                        \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet nature de l\'exposition')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/declaration.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

An example call within the CRUD panel is :

```
       namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
       use App\Services\ProcessService;   
       ...
       CRUD::setValidation(DeclarationRequest::class);

       $id = $this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->id;
       $NbSuivis = $this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->NbSuivis;

       ProcessService::validatePanel(2, $NbSuivis, $id);
```

## Problem

This produces **too many redirects**

## Workaround

However, when I embed the switch statement directly in the various CRUD controllers, everything works flawlessly.

How can I keep this logic out of the controller and in a class definition ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the embedded switch statements. Break statements are required as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class ProcessService

{

    public static function validatePanel(int $NbPanel, int $NbSuivis, int $id): void
    {


        switch ($NbPanel) {

            case 2: {

                    switch ($NbSuivis) {
                        case -1:
                            \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                            redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                            redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 3:
                switch ($NbSuivis) {
                    case -1:
                        \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet nature de l\'exposition')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/declaration.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                switch ($NbSuivis) {
                    case -1:
                        \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet nature de l\'exposition')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/declaration.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        \Alert::add('error', 'Veuillez compléter l\'onglet personne source')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/personne_source.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                switch ($NbSuivis) {
                    case -1:
                        \Alert::error('Exposition en suivi externe')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet d\'identification')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/identification.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet nature de l\'exposition')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/declaration.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet personne source')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/personne_source.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        \Alert::error('Veuillez compléter l\'onglet état sérologique')->flash();
                        redirect()->route('exposition/etat.edit', ['id' => $id])->send();
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```